# Horizontal centering inside a position: absolute element

Tags: css, html, position, css-position

The `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` way to horizontally center something works well when the container is `static` or `relative` positioned but seems to fail when it is `absolute` positioned.

Is there a way to get the `auto` margins to work in this situation? I need the container to be `absolute` for certain reasons.

Comment: Could you please post some sample code including your CSS styling so that your question can be more appropriately addressed?

Comment: I'm a bit confused -- absolute positioning puts the element at an x,y coordinate.  So what do you want to center?

Comment: Alright, alright... making a fiddle now...

Comment: It is working quite well for me. Does your inner element have width set?

Comment: Hm. Okay so the thing I'm trying to center is a `<code>` element and even when setting `display: inline-block` on it, it fails to behave properly. I'll have to fix up my code to use a `div` and i'll be fine. The fiddle I made worked fine.

Comment: Actually I was still wrong about that too. Here's the fiddle that correctly centers a `<pre><code>` block http://jsfiddle.net/U5u3H/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

absolute positioning is, by definition, going to use 0,0 as a point of reference for your positioning.

What I would suggest is using a container with position:absolute and width 100%, and then specifying with a position: 0 auto anything you want centered.

Comment: Indeed the usage of a `position: absolute` container `width: 100%` should work